# Remove dialog screen for crm lead when click on create button for Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, kanban

I am using Odoo 11. And i want to remove open dialog wizard when click on create button on kanban view instead of open full view of crm lead form. So, How to remove dialog box wizard from create button?

Also attaching screenshot.

PFA
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you could just find and edit that kanban view in order to remove this attr: `on_create="crm.create_opportunity_simplified"`

You could do it easy with developer mode activated by editing the kanban view in that menu.

If you wanna do it in a module with xml view inheritance, you could do it like:

```
<record id="crm_case_kanban_view_leads" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.lead</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//kanban" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="on_create"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```